# Why do I have still an undefined reference?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

A minimal example:

test.c:

```
void foo() {
}
```

testapp.c:

```
extern void foo();
void main() {
    foo();
}
```

Compile the library:

```
gcc -fpic -c -o test.o test.c
gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

Check if foo is really available:

```
nm libtest.so | grep foo
00000000000010f9 T foo
```

Compile the application:

```
gcc -L. -ltest testapp.c
```

Getting always this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccn9kMmH.o: in function `main':
testapp.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Why do I have still an *undefined reference*?**

Comment: it should be `gcc -L. testapp.c  -ltest`. [`-l` flag comes after the .c file](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)

Comment: Wow, this did the job! Should I write an answer whit your content?